# deleteDuplicates singly-linkedlist C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement deleteDuplicates given a linkedlist in C.  I'm running into problems with a segFault and I'm not sure why.  My test case giving it a linked list with two nodes, each with data 3 is below.  In my deleteDups, you will see two commented out if-blocks.  If I uncomment it, I won't have a segFault and the code appears to work fine.

Why is that the case?  It seems to me the if statement is exactly what the while loop checks for...

Thanks in advance!

my node structure and code

```
typedef struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} *node;


void deleteDups(node *head)
{
   if (!*head)
        return;
   node current = *head;
   node runner;
   while (current)
   {
        runner = current;
        while (runner->next)
        {
            if (runner->next->data == current->data)
            {
                node tmp = runner->next;
                runner->next = runner->next->next;
                free(tmp);
            }
            /*if(runner->next == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }*/
            runner = runner->next;

        }
        /*if (current->next == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }*/ 
        current = current->next;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

node one = (node) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
one->data = 3;
one->next = NULL;

node head = (node) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
head->data = 3;
head->next = one;

printList(head);
deleteDups(&head);
printList(head);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the inner loop condition and the assignment

```
runner = runner->next;
```

Since you only have two nodes, and delete the last, the above assignment will make `runner` equal to `NULL`. You then check for `runner->next` in the loop condition.

This would have been *very* easy to find in a debugger, especially if you used it to step through the code line by line to see what happened. I recommend you try that the next time.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it segfaults is: At the end of the first iteration of the inner while loop the value of runner is null, and calling an operation ->next results in segfault.

Stepping through to elaborate how the above happenes:

You have a linked list of two nodes. At the start of the inner while loop below,

```
runner points to the first node,       
runner->next points to second node, and    
runner->next->next points to null
```

At the end of the first iteration, there is only one node and hence, runner->next is null . (After the first commented if statement) runner is assigned the value of runner->next. So the value of runner is now NULL.

At the start of the next iteration, the check runner->next results in a segFault because runner is NULL.

--
In addition, to make sure your function works for an empty list, you should check for if (!head) instead of if (!*head)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your NULL check for runner->next.When you execute these two line for the last node in the list your runner becomes NULL.

`runner->next = runner->next->next;` <--- Runner's next is NULL here.

`.....`

`runner = runner->next;` <-- Runner is NULL now.

In the next iteration the runner->next crashes. 
the while loop condition should be like this:
`while(runner & runner->next)`

-MS